# AngularJS - how to set up $watch on multiple values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to watch on model changes in an object that sits in the controller. The object has multiple values:

```
$scope.myModel = {
   first: 1,
   second: 1,
   third: 1
}
```

I want to catch changes to any of these values, but don't want to set up multiple watchers on each individual value, as it seems wasteful. Can I set up one `$watch` that triggers when anything in the model has changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass true as a third argument to the $watch function, see the [docs for scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) :

> $watch(watchExpression, [listener], [objectEquality]);
>   (...) ObjectEquality: Compare for object equality using angular.equals instead of comparing for reference equality

When objectEquality is false or not set, that means it will only check if it's the *same* object or not. Instead, setting it to true it will check if they are actually equal or not.

So the watch would look like:

```
$scope.$watch('variable', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // function code
}, true);
```

Comment: In addition, I would add some example based on SO's question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.$watch("myModel",function(v){

console.log(v);

},true)
```

Should do it. The `true` parameter is needed since you're watching child properties.